# Grub rescue unknown file system(changed to ntfs from ext 4)

Tags: 16.04

In order to change my laptop from Ubuntu to windows I changed my filesystem from ext4 to NTFS. Now it is showing error unknown file system(Grub rescue). Is there any way I can exit from that.

Comment: Do you have the Windows install DVD or USB drive?

Comment: I have a windows usb drive with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just install Windows. It should erase GRUB and install its own bootloader.

1. First, if you have any files you want to keep from the computer's drive, stop now and ask for help. Continuing can delete them forever.
2. Boot your computer from the Windows install USB drive.
   While installing if it shows the following error "    Windows Cannot be installed on this type of format"
   Go back to screen which shows install windows screen.

   <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd>

   diskpart

   disk list

   select disk 0(In general hard disk will be in disk 0).

   clean.

   Exit.

   Close it and continue installing OS
3. Let Windows install.

Comment: I am trying to install Win 8. While I am trying to boot, it is going directly to grub rescue. Is not showing any windows install screen.

Comment: You can usually get a boot menu by pressing `F12` repeatedly while the system is first booting. If that works, choose to boot from the USB drive.